# How to align Google Maps Iframe and a box?

Tags: html, css

I want to align the Google Maps box and the text bow in the same line, but I can't.

I've already tried with `position: relative` and changed the `top` and `left` sizes, but despite they were aligned, a huge blank space took place on the bottom.

```css
.ind-mapa {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.resp-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ind-media {
  float: left;
  border: 0.5px #f6e8d5 solid;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-left: 50vw;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #cccccc;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ind-contato">
  <div class="ind-mapa" style="display: inline-block;">
    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6150.579385265073!2d-46.595158112257735!3d-23.56282631464785!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce5eb2bb2e0fd7%3A0x598f639056140b1f!2sR.+do+Orat%C3%B3rio%2C+1036+-+Mooca%2C+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP%2C+03118-030!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1548656882243"
      frameborder="0" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 0.5px #f6e8d5 solid; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #cccccc;" align="left" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <div class="ind-media" style="display: inline-block;">
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex layout does the trick:

```css
.ind-mapa {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.ind-mapa>* {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}

.resp-iframe {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ind-mapa">
  <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6150.579385265073!2d-46.595158112257735!3d-23.56282631464785!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce5eb2bb2e0fd7%3A0x598f639056140b1f!2sR.+do+Orat%C3%B3rio%2C+1036+-+Mooca%2C+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP%2C+03118-030!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1548656882243"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

  <div class="ind-media">
    I want to align the Google Maps box and the text bow in the same line, but I can't. I've already tried with position: relative and changed the top and left sizes, but despite they were aligned, a huge blank space took place on the bottom.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @RafaelaSouza, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

`CSS Flexbox` will do the job, see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

See snippet with a minimal working sample.

---

Also you did not close the div's properly.

> I've already tried with position: relative and changed the top and
>   left sizes, but despite they were aligned, a huge blank space took
>   place on the bottom.

On your code, the MAP is not getting the full height because you positioned the `iframe` as `position: absolute;` and did not set the height, so if you set `.resp-iframe` with `height: 100%;` the iframe will be at the same height as it's parent.

Viva Mooca bella!

```css
.ind-contato {
  display: flex;
}
.ind-contato > div,
.ind-contato > iframe {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="ind-contato">
    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d6150.579385265073!2d-46.595158112257735!3d-23.56282631464785!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x94ce5eb2bb2e0fd7%3A0x598f639056140b1f!2sR.+do+Orat%C3%B3rio%2C+1036+-+Mooca%2C+S%C3%A3o+Paulo+-+SP%2C+03118-030!5e0!3m2!1spt-BR!2sbr!4v1548656882243"
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <div class="ind-media">
      Box on the side.
    </div>
  
 </div>
```